# Смена цвета кнопки при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Что нужно дописать в скрипт, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Записаться", она выделялась определенным цветом, и оставалась такой до тех пор, пока пользователь не нажмет на нее еще раз, или на другую кнопку.

**P.S.** CSS active не работает.

```css
a{
  background: #ad9c6a;
  color:#fff;
  padding: 12px 50px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #5f4f21;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script>
function openbox(id) {
  var all = document.querySelectorAll(".block-of-text");
  for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    if (all[i].id == id) {
      all[i].style.display = (all[i].style.display == 'none')? 'block' : 'none';
    } else {
      all[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
</script>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="openbox('box1'); return false">Записаться</a>
<a href="#" onclick="openbox('box2'); return false">Записаться</a>
<br><br><br>
<div class="block-of-text" id="box1" style="display: none;">Отображаемый блок 1</div>
<div class="block-of-text" id="box2" style="display: none;">Отображаемый блок 2</div>
```

Comment: у вас тут точно jquery тэг уместен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, как так? если тэг jquery вы поставили не ошибочно, конечно.

```js
$(".reg-btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".reg-btn").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    
    var bId =  $(this).data('block');
    $(".block-of-text").not(bId).toggle(false);
    $(bId).toggle();
});
```

```css
a{
  background: #ad9c6a;
  color:#fff;
  padding: 12px 50px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
a:hover, a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #5f4f21;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  color:#fff;
}

.block-of-text { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<a href="#" class="reg-btn" data-block="#box1">Записаться</a>
<a href="#" class="reg-btn" data-block="#box2">Записаться</a>
<br><br><br>

<div class="block-of-text" id="box1" >Отображаемый блок 1</div>
<div class="block-of-text" id="box2" >Отображаемый блок 2</div>
```

Comment: Реализовать на Jquery тоже можно. У вас даже проще получилось. Так что можно и с ним. Но в Вашем примере при повторном нажатии на кнопку, блок с текстом не закрывается.

Comment: Не могли вы бы сделать, чтобы по нажатию блок скрывался тоже?

Comment: @FlapJack подправил

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!